# Jenkinsfile access aws credentials

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to access AWS credentials stored in Jenkins with following in jenkins pipeline (`Jenkinsfile`)

```
steps {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'eb1092d1-0f06-4bf9-93c7-32e5f7b9ef76', accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')]) {
                sh 'echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
                sh 'echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
            }
      }
```

Its erroring with

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.CredentialNotFoundException: Could not find credentials entry with ID 'eb1092d1-0f06-4bf9-93c7-32e5f7b9ef76'
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.MultiBinding.getCredentials(MultiBinding.java:153)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.UsernamePasswordMultiBinding.bind(UsernamePasswordMultiBinding.java:76)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.BindingStep$Execution.start(BindingStep.java:114)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:270)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:178)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3000.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:155)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:16)
```

And with

```
withCredentials([[ $class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', credentialsId: 'eb1092d1-0f06-4bf9-93c7-32e5f7b9ef76', accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) {
                sh "echo this is ${env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"
                sh "echo this is ${env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}"
            }
```

Erroring

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.CredentialNotFoundException: Could not find credentials entry with ID 'eb1092d1-0f06-4bf9-93c7-32e5f7b9ef76'
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.MultiBinding.getCredentials(MultiBinding.java:153)
at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.awscredentials.AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding.bind(AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding.java:97)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.BindingStep$Execution.start(BindingStep.java:114)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:270)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:178)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3000.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
at
```

I do have credentials with ID `eb1092d1-0f06-4bf9-93c7-32e5f7b9ef76`

I have installed **CloudBees AWS Credentials Plugin**  Version 1.24

anyone know whats wrong here ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The credential `eb1092d1-0f06-4bf9-93c7-32e5f7b9ef76` is not a `AWS access key and secret` type. Please double check you choose the right type when you add the credential to Jenkins.

And you can check via Jenkins built-in tool: Pipeline Syntax -> Snippet Generator as following guide:

1. Open the tool via `your jenkins server url/pipeline-syntax/`, example https://my.jenkins.com/pipeline-syntax/
2. Choose `withCredentials: Bind credentials to variables` from sample step dropdown
3. Click Add button and Choose `AWS access key and secret` from pop-up options
4. Choose your credential from `Credentials` dropdown, if you can't find any one in the dropdown, means your credential is not `AWS access key and secret` type
5. Click `Generate pipeline script` button
6. Check the `credentialsId` in generated script is `eb1092d1-0f06-4bf9-93c7-32e5f7b9e`

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Converting the code from the screenshot above to a snippet for easy copying

```
withCredentials([[
    $class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',
    credentialsId: "credentials-id-here",
    accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
    secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
]]) {
    // AWS Code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's now 2023 and aws credentials have a `withCredentials` binding as per the [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/):

```
 withCredentials([aws(credentialsId: "aws_credentials_id")]) {
    sh '''
       #!/bin/bash
       aws ...
       '''.stripIndent().stripLeading()
 }
```

The documentation snippet of interest:

> Sets one variable to the AWS access key and another one to the secret key given in the credentials.
>
> - `accessKeyVariable` : String
>   Environment variable name for the AWS Access Key Id. If empty, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` will be used.
> - `secretKeyVariable` : String
>   Environment variable name for the AWS Secret Access Key. If empty, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` will be used.
> - `credentialsId` : String
>   Credentials of an appropriate type to be set to the variable.
> - `roleArn` : String (optional)
> - `roleSessionDurationSeconds` : int (optional)
> - `roleSessionName` : String (optional)

You can also use these credentials from a parameter input even though that is [not documented](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters). Just make sure the `credentialsId` is set to the name of the pipeline parameter:

```
    parameters {
        credentials(credentialType: 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.awscredentials.AWSCredentialsImpl',
            defaultValue: '',
            description: 'AWS Credentials for AMI Generation',
            // the credentials name used here must match the parameter passed to userColonPassword in the 'Deploy' stage below
            name: 'aws_credentials',
            required: true)
    }

 ...

 withCredentials([aws(credentialsId: "aws_credentials")]) {
    sh '''
       #!/bin/bash
       aws ...
       '''.stripIndent().stripLeading()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to deal with multi-field credentials or vendor-specific credential types that the plugin does not (yet) support.

In this situation you have a couple of choices:

1. Use the closest standard multi-field credential (e.g. Username With Password) that fits your requirements.
2. Use a string credential, serialize all the fields into the secret value (e.g. as JSON or as a delimited string), and parse them in the job script. (This is a last resort when other methods don't work, e.g. when secret rotation would cause multiple fields to change.)

Example: Jenkins authenticates to Secrets Manager using the primary AWS credential (from the environment). You have a job that performs a particular AWS operation in a different account, which uses a secondary AWS credential. You choose to encode the secondary AWS credential as JSON in the string credential foo:

```
node {
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'foo', variable: 'secret')]) {
        script {
            def creds = readJSON text: secret
            env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = creds['accessKeyId']
            env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = creds['secretAccessKey']
            env.AWS_REGION = 'us-east-1' // or whatever
        }
        sh "aws sts get-caller-identity" // or whatever
    }
}
```

A typical example of a username password type credential (example from here) would look like:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'amazon', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
  // available as an env variable, but will be masked if you try to print it out any which way
  // note: single quotes prevent Groovy interpolation; expansion is by Bourne Shell, which is what you want
  sh 'echo $PASSWORD'
  // also available as a Groovy variable
  echo USERNAME
  // or inside double quotes for string interpolation
  echo "username is $USERNAME"
}
```

[ReadMore1](https://plugins.jenkins.io/aws-secrets-manager-credentials-provider/)

[ReadMore2](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials-binding/)