# How to set AWS credentials in Jenkins?

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins

I am trying to read a table from the below code which works fine in windows but as I run it in Jenkins docker container, gives the below error.

My code to read the dynamo tb is below-

```
 AmazonDynamoDB ClientObj = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("xx-xxxx-1").build();
        DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(ClientObj);
        Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("xxxxxx");
        String app_type = "xxxxxx";
        String MSG_Id = Res_ID;
        GetItemSpec spec = new GetItemSpec().withPrimaryKey("app_type", app_type, "messageID", MSG_Id);
        try {
            log.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Attempting to read the item...");
            Item outcome = table.getItem(spec);
            log.log(LogStatus.INFO, "GetItem succeeded: " + outcome);
```

> Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain:
>   [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS
>   credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or
>   AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)),
>   SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials
>   from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey),
>   com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@422b3532:
>   Duplicate property values for [aws_access_key_id].,
>   com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@5d6916d4:
>   Unable to load credentials from service endpoint]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkinsfile access aws credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53859575/jenkinsfile-access-aws-credentials)

Comment: Assign a rule to your Jenkins instance. you do not need to mentioned keys. Keys discourage as much as possible